# MySQL set default value of a column as a divide formula of two others

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL and trying to push myself. Right now I've created a very simple table `(title, author, page_count, current_page, %,genre)`

I want to set %'s default value = to current_page/page_count.

How would I do this.

Also any ideas to push myself and create the best booklist table are welcome.

Thanks!

Current code:

```
CREATE TABLE Booklist1(
    Title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Author varchar(100),
    Page_Count INT,
    Genre varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(Title));
```

Comment: What made you think you could use an expression as default value in MySQL?

Comment: It was more of a hope I suppose. If I cannot make it a default how can I manually do it? 

I am still very new at MySQL

Comment: I think you can in MSSQL but not in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Have you considered using a trigger?

Comment: @JoeLove I do not know what that is.... still very new to the language

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.1 supports [expressions as DEFAULT value](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default). For earlier versions and MySQL you would need to write a trigger.

Comment: ALTER TABLE Booklist1 ADD % INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (Current_Page/Page_Count);

Is this how it would be done?

Answer (score 2):

In the more recent versions of MySQL, you would use a generated column:

```
alter table booklist1
    add percentage decimal (3, 2) as (current_page * 100.0 / nullif(page_count, 0) );
```

In earlier versions you would use a view or a trigger.

Comment: Could someone please check more work? I am starting off smaller. Essentially trying to make a trigger that when I enter Current_Page into my booklist and it matches Page_Count my table column of Finished that is set by default to no will switch to yes.

  Delimiter $$
    CREATE TRIGGER after_finisher_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON Booklist1
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Booklist1
        SET Finished = 'yes'
        WHERE Current_Page = Page_Count
    END
    Delimiter $$

Comment: @marctoney . . . Code belongs in a question, not a comment.